# Variable with 3 states (with one of those states variable as well)

Tags: c, types

I get this is a tricky question but I'll try to explain it in the best way I can.

I want a variable to be able to assume one out of 3 possible values, two of them are specific "flag values" (`STATE1` and `STATE2`), the third one is a number `unsigned long`.

So, for example, I could have an array like this:

```
{STATE1, 3984902, 20304, STATE2, STATE1, 3021289129}
```

Is it possible to do such a thing in C?

Comment: Struct with two fields. One will indicate STATE1 through STATE3, and then when it is STATE3, it will look at the second field with the int value. But I would guess you have interpreted your assignment too literally.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's what I was looking for, if you make it an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a structure with two fields, while the first field will indicate one of these custom discrete states with one extra state which will indicate that the other field to be used as the numeric value:

```
typedef enum 
{
    STATE1, 
    STATE2,
    STATE3
} dstate_t;

typedef struct
{
    dstate_t dstate;   // Discrete state
    unsigned long val;  // The value for STATE3
} state_t;
```

Then you can have an array of `state_t` such as

```
{{STATE1, 0}, {STATE3, 3984902}, {STATE3,20304}, {STATE2, 0}, {STATE1, 0}, {STATE3,3021289129}}
```

Comment: Thanks again! Just one question: why are you using `typedef` here? Would there be any problem if I was not using it?

Comment: @Robb1 Then you will have to carry the `enum` and `struct` keywords along all of the way. Just convenience.

Comment: ... and that's a pure stylistic consideration about which opinions vary.

Comment: Convenience _and_ industry standard everywhere. (Except in Linux code bases, where they frown at not having to write `struct` all over the code, no rationale given.)

Comment: I'd certainly accept "widely used", @Lundin, but "industry standard everywhere" seems a bit strong, even with your exception.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know of no other code base than the Linux ones that uses that style. Notably, using typedef makes your code style compatible/consistent with C++ and with pretty much every other mainstream programming language that uses types.

Comment: @Lundin, I am confident that you very well know that "I know of no other style" is not at all the same thing as "there is no other style".  And I observe, too, that although POSIX is by no means consistent in this area, there are multiple data structures used by POSIX interfaces for which POSIX does not define a `typedef`.  The C standard library even does this -- `struct timespec`, for example. This is much broader than "Linux code bases".